# Looking for Hello World program for Solr.NET in C#

Tags: c#, solr, solrnet

I have Solr server running (on Linux box, not that it matter), it is loaded with 2M documents and search works fine in Java.

I need however to write C# (client) program to query it. I downloaded Solr.NET but I am confused what to begin with. Solutions included with it do not compile, and browsing through C# it does not look like the program is doing what I need to do.

Does anyone have a sort of Hello World program for Solr.NET in C#? Below I will publish Java version of what I and looking for, C# version anyone? Oh, and please, what minimum set of assemblies do I need to include into such simple client program? Thank you

```
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrQuery;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServer;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.response.QueryResponse;
import org.apache.solr.common.SolrDocumentList;


public class SolrHeloWorld // Java
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Connect to server
        SolrServer solr = new HttpSolrServer  ("http://192.168.1.211:8983/solr/collection1");

        // Query for search term 'banana'
        SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
        query.setQuery("banana");
        query.setStart(0);
        query.setRows(50);
        query.set("defType", "edismax");

        try
        {
            QueryResponse response = solr.query(query);

            // Print results
            SolrDocumentList results = response.getResults();
            for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++)
            {
                System.out.println(results.get(i));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try the [Documentation](https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/blob/master/Documentation/README.md)?

Comment: Documentation? The one that came with Solr.NET download does not have much in there. There is a directory called Documentation with few short *.md files in there. The one called Queying.md has a few one liners in there, but nothing close to a complete code example.  More importantly no document lists namespaces/assemblies I need to include to even make in compile.

Comment: And the on-line documentation that is your link does not have what I am looking for either. It starts with "First, we have to map the Solr document to a class". No we absolutely don't have to do that. I want to retrieve JSON from Solr. I al looking for bare bone example, without class mappings, without unit tests and etc. And please-please-please I need a set of namespaces/assemblies to include.

Comment: Take a better look at the documentation: https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/blob/master/Documentation/Basic-usage.md and https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/blob/master/Documentation/Sample-application.md

Answer (score 5):

As suggested I have take another closer look at documentation for Solr.NET. Still, I wasn’t able to figure out which assemblies are missing in solutions that came with download so they still do not compile! More importantly it does not appear that you can write bare bone program that simply prints JSON without NHibernate, defining class mapping and all that.

Never the less, it is not that hard to write simple Hello World client program in C# that queries Solr. And it does not require Solr.NET at all! Here is the one that uses HttpWebRequest and JSON serializer/deserializer to simply print JSON of all documents returned by query

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization; // Require adding System.Web.Extentions.dll

class SolrHeloWorld // C#
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Uri uri = new Uri("http://192.168.1.211:8983/solr/collection1/select?q=banana&start=0&rows=50&wt=json&indent=true&defType=edismax");

        WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        string jsonResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();
        response.Close();

        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        dynamic jsonObject = serializer.Deserialize<dynamic>(jsonResponse);
        dynamic dd = jsonObject["response"]["docs"]; 
        Object[] results = (Object[])dd;

        foreach (Object res in results)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(serializer.Serialize(res));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If something doesn't compile, I recommend asking a specific question about that in https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/solrnet . If you're new to .NET I recommend changing a bit the attitude of "I just want to do it my way!", and instead first trying to learn how things are done differently. Things like "Please translate this piece of code for me" are usually not well received in Stackoverflow. If you don't want to map Solr documents to a class (though I don't recommend it), see https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/blob/master/Documentation/Mapping.md#fully-loose-mapping .

Comment: @ Mauricio Scheffer: I wasn't asking to translate my code into another language. I was hoping that Solr C# Hello Word program already exists and somebody would provide a link. But I probably was away from the earth for some time and I did not realize that simple Hello Word style programs are out of fashion these days. Apparently including any kind of complete (and compliable) example with documentation rather than set one-liners is out of faction too. My fault - I should definitely catch with the trend.  
Thanks for google group though.

Comment: Just in case, once again I'll point to the sample app: https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/blob/master/Documentation/Sample-application.md , it's a full web application far beyond a "Hello World". Also https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/blob/master/Documentation/Basic-usage.md is a walkthrough of the normal usage of the library, equivalent to a Hello World. I don't know what more could you want.

Comment: IMHO the web app is a little overcomplicated and kinda misses the point (i.e. has a lot of helpers, views, and just one controller that only searches - does not index!), while in the "Overview and Basic Usage" pages there's no mention of the namespaces where things can be found or other architectural organization explanations... I'm trying to migrate an application from Lucene.NET to Solr, and SolrNet's documentation is next to useless in my use case.

Answer (score 2):

There is a course in Pluralsight that gets you started with Solr and SolrNet. The last module is about SolrNet specifically:

http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/enterprise-search-using-apache-solr